# What does retain apk do exactly

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, apk

I retained my previous apk and rolled out a new one at 5% but seems devices with the previous version doesn't get updates even when I increased the version number for the new apk. Only new installs are getting the new apk.

The other settings like target sdk etc are all the same.

Comment: You know, I have the same question. My one experiment with this failed miserably, and I had to change the version number, reupload it, and not retain the apk.
Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you roll out at 5% you only expect one user in 20 to get the new APK. Have you actually done the experiment with more than 20 existing users?

Comment: I understand that '1 in 20 new installs' gets the updated apk, but '1 in 20 of existing users' don't get an update even when the version number changed.